# Why does root element is missing message is appear?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Why does a message appear when trying to add new item to the solution in Visual Studio?
Solution explorer -> mouse right click -> New Item -> Windows Form -> Root element is missing !

Comment: Sounds like your Solution/Project file is corrupt.

Comment: and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your solution and open the project in VS. Hopefully that'll fix it. If not , guess you'll have to recreate the project from your files.